# Serializing BigInteger in java

Tags: java, serialization, biginteger

I have to write a biginteger into a text file using the following statement.

```
out.writeObject(n1);
```

where my n1 is a biginteger of length 512 bits.

On reading the same object from the text file gives me a different value to n1. Could anyone help me with the problem. 
The statement used to read the value is :

```
in.readObject();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show more code. Serialization of `BigInteger` objects generally doesn't change the value.

Comment: FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("file.txt");
ObjectOutputStream out= new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
out.writeObject(n1);

Comment: @Mandikan: Please edit your question and add that code to it. Do not post code in comments, if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to post [SSCCE](http://homepage1.nifty.com/algafield/sscce.html), so here is one for you:

```
BigInteger big = new BigInteger("515377520732011331036461129765621272702107522001");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
outputStream.writeObject(big);
byte[] rawBytes = baos.toByteArray();

ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(rawBytes));
BigInteger bigReadBack = (BigInteger) inputStream.readObject();

assertThat(big).isEqualTo(bigReadBack);
```

Works like a charm, serializing and deserializing `3^100`. Can you try the code above?

UPDATE: example with file (sorry for non-descriptive variable names):

```
BigInteger big = new BigInteger("515377520732011331036461129765621272702107522001");
OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("big.ser");
ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
outputStream.writeObject(big);
fos.close();

ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("big.ser"));
BigInteger bigReadBack = (BigInteger) inputStream.readObject();

assertThat(big).isEqualTo(bigReadBack);
```

BTW storing Java-serialized binary data in a file with `.txt` extension is generally a bad idea... And don't forget about caching! (`BufferedInputStream`/`BufferedOutputstream`).

Comment: But i need to store it in a file.. How could it help me?